# Advanced 2 speaker configuration, Windows8

Tags: windows-8.1, speakers

I've just got a 5.0 home theater, which became 2.0 x2 because of the layout of my room. The speakers are laid out like so:

[image]

C and D are 3-channel (= element) speakers for watching TV, A and B are 2-channel "rear" tin cans used for PC. These tin cans need more low end from C or D. The television is connected to PC, as is amp with 2x 3,5mm to 2xRCA cable. Sound Card is integrated into  Asus m5a78l/usb3 motherboard, Chipset seems to be Realtek ALC887,

I'm looking to set up 2 configurations with easy switching from PC (pref. command line):

- For sofa: C and D on, A and B off (= just no signal from pc to amp).
- For PC chair: A and B on, C and/or D bass only, LPF/EQ on PC side.

I'd imagine the problem is so specific, I'm probably looking for a niche tool. However, I have no idea what such a tool would be called, what to Google, or where to get started.

Comment: You should specify what sound card you are using. Whether a tool exists for your sound card depends on what sound card it is. Alternatively there are all-software solutions.

Comment: Hey qasdfdsaq, my sound card is an integrated version on Asus M5A78L-M/USB3 motherboard. The chipset seems to be Realtek ALC887.

Answer (score 2):

You might be approaching this unrealistically. Two solutions that work but are not what you describe:

1. Upgrade A & B to be able to handle the audio alone; buy a cheap second sound card; easily switch between your two setups with the windows audio panel.
2. Use a receiver for C & D, set up A & B for independent zone 2. You can switch between them easily.

I've never seen a tool that does crossover type adjustments for different speaker setups - it's an extremely uncommon problem.